# Promise returned in function argument where a void return was expected

Tags: javascript, typescript, electron

I'm working on an Electron application and I want to use async await in an anonymous function in my Main like this:

```
process.on("uncaughtException", async (error: Error) => {
  await this.errorHandler(error);
});
```

But this yields the Typescript error

> Promise returned in function argument where a void return was
> expected.

I'm using Typescript 3.9.7 and Electron 9.2.0.

Why doesn't it allow me to use async/await?

Comment: An `async` function *always* returns a promise, so it can't be passed where a void function is expected. Why not just call the error handler, what are you trying to wait for?

Comment: In general, don't pass `async` functions into things that won't use the promise they return. TypeScript is helping you avoid doing that with this error.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You can use an asynchronous [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) inside the callback, like this:

```
process.on("uncaughtException", (error: Error) => {
  (async () => {
    await this.errorHandler(error);

    // ...
  })();
});
```

This ensures that the implicit return of the callback remains `undefined`, rather than being a promise.

Comment: Just be sure to handle promise rejection correctly.

Comment: Is there a good reason to do that, beyond removing the eslint error?

Comment: @Henrique Bruno Functionally, no. Semantically, yes — it signals clearly that this is a "fire and forget" operation and that the callback itself doesn't do anything special with the asynchronous code (doesn't await it or do anything with the result).

Comment: @LionelRowe Simple and mind expanding answer. Thanks!

I will, however, keep this ESLint rule disabled as I think that it being enabled, adds an unnecessary complexity and verbosity level for my uses.

Comment: I have a similar case here:

onClick={ () =>
UtilClass.getName(a, b).then(
    (name) => {
            UtilClass.delete(name, x, y);
     })
}

It is giving me @typescript-eslint/no-misused-promises error. How should I fix it in my case?

Answer (score 21):

Fixed it, I found the answer below from [here](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/4619#issuecomment-1055614155)

```
 <div
  onClick={
    () => {
      void doSomethingAsync();
    }
  }
  onClick={
    () => {
      void (async () => {
        const x = await doSomethingAsync();
        doSomethingElse(X);
      })();
    }
  }
/>
```

Comment: it works but it looks awfull, I'd rather disable the rule lol

Comment: I have a similar case here:

onClick={ () =>
UtilClass.getName(a, b).then(
    (name) => {
            UtilClass.delete(name, x, y);
     })
}

It is giving me @typescript-eslint/no-misused-promises error. How should I fix it in my case?

Comment: This actually affects the outcome of the callback in button elements. I've experienced a preventDefault() bug, it submits the form regardless. removing the void solved it.

Answer (score 13):

You can turn off this check (not the entire rule) with the help of `checksVoidReturn` [option](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-misused-promises.md#options):

.eslinter.js

```
rules: {
    {
      "@typescript-eslint/no-misused-promises": [
        "error",
        {
          "checksVoidReturn": false
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

But I strongly recommend not to do this and rewrite your code using `.then` and `.catch` to avoid hitting this linter error.

You may also disable this rule inline with `// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-misused-promises` comment above this particular occurrence along with a few lines of comment describing why you think this is okay to ignore the error.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply remove async keyword from the lambda function and add catch clause to prevent an unhandled promise rejection.

```js
process.on("uncaughtException", (error: Error) => {
  this.errorHandler(error).catch((e) => console.error(e));
});
```

The reason you are getting this error is, `process.on` expects its lambda function to return `void`, not `Promise<void>`, and your lambda function is never going to be awaited.

This is important, because without await keyword an unhandled promise rejection may be triggered which crashes the entire process immediately.

Look at the following example:

```
function middleware(f) {
    f();
}

middleware(async () => {
    throw "Error!";
});
```

Now, when I run this file, an error message will pop up:

```
node:internal/process/promises:289
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^
[UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason "Error!".] {
  code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION'
}
```

This is because the promise was never awaited, and therefore Node.js didn't know what to do with the error thrown by the promise.

Simply adding catch like this clause will fix the problem.

```
function middleware(f) {
    f().catch((e) => console.error(e));
}

middleware(async () => {
    throw "Error!";
});
```

Note: adding catch clause is not mandatory in a browser environment because unhandled promise rejection will not result in immediate crash in the browser environment.

Answer (score -2):

This is the official TS ESLint solution and I recommend you update your `.eslintrc` config file with:

```
"@typescript-eslint/no-misused-promises": [
    2,
    {
        "checksVoidReturn": {
            "attributes": false
        }
    },
]
```

Check this Pull Request for more info https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/pull/4623