# Use an asynchronous IIFE inside the callback

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, eslint

How do I use an asynchronous IIFE inside the callback as per this example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63488201/436493) to avoid the error message: **Promise returned in function argument where a void return was expected**.

```
  signIn(email: string, password: string, course?: ICourse): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise<UserCredential>((resolve, reject) =>
      this.afAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(
        (res) => {
          resolve(res);
        },
        (error: { message: string }) => {
          reject(error);
          this.toastrService.warning('Something has gone wrong. Please try again.', 'Oops!');
          this.logger.debug('An error occurred during Email Sign In');
          this.logger.error(error.message);
        }
      )
    ).then(
      (result: UserCredential) => {
        if (course && result.user) {
          this.builderSignIn(course, result.user.uid);
        } else {
          if (result != null) {
            this.ngZone.run(() => {
              void this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
            });
          }
        }
      },
      (error: { message: string }) => {
        this.toastrService.warning(error.message, 'Oops!');
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: If you can write an async IIFE, why not just make signIn async? Then it's easier to read and you can guarantee a void promise with a bare `return;`.

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Comment: What tool is giving that error message? On what line/function specifically?

Comment: No, you should not use an IIFE. And are you saying that you want to use `async`/`await`?

Comment: @Bergi the error message happens at `return new Promise<UserCredential>((resolve, reject) =>`. I'm not sure what I should use. I'd just like to figure out a way to get rid of the ESLint error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `new Promise` executor callback should return `void`, but you're passing an arrow function with a concise body that implicitly returns the value. You *could* easily fix that by doing

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
//                                      ^
   … /*
})
^ */
```

but really you just [shouldn't be using the `Promise` constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it) at all! Simply

```
signIn(email: string, password: string, course?: ICourse): Promise<void> {
  return this.afAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then((result: UserCredential) => {
    if (course && result.user) {
      this.builderSignIn(course, result.user.uid);
    } else {
      if (result != null) {
        this.ngZone.run(() => {
          void this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
        });
      }
    }
  }, (error: { message: string }) => {
    this.toastrService.warning('Something has gone wrong. Please try again.', 'Oops!');
    this.logger.debug('An error occurred during Email Sign In');
    this.logger.error(error.message);
    this.toastrService.warning(error.message, 'Oops!');
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks this looks and works amazingly well! Appreciate it!