# Immediately Invoked Function Expression to solve Typescript return type error is not working

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, typescript-eslint

I am working on a Typescript project and linter is giving me this error:

```
Promise-returning function provided to attribute where a void return was expected
```

I've tried the IIFE solution from this post:
[Promise returned in function argument where a void return was expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63488141/promise-returned-in-function-argument-where-a-void-return-was-expected)

so the code becomes:

```tsx
onClick={() => {
  (async () => {
    await removeUserHandler({
      id: user.id                                    
    });
  })();
}}
```

Then I start to get a different error:

```
Promises must be awaited, end with a call to .catch, end with a call to .then with a rejection handler or be explicitly marked as ignored with the `void` operator.
```

It does make sense to me what it is saying but struggling to resolve it.

**My Function:**

```ts
const removeUserHandler = async (user: User): Promise<void> => {
  try {
    const removeUserResponse = await api.removeUser(user);

    if (removeUserResponse.code === "") {
      console.log("Success!!!");
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

And then the button with **clickHandler**:

```tsx
<Button 
  onClick={() =>
    removeUserHandler({
      id: user.id
     }) 
  }
/>
```

Appreciate if anyone can provide some guidance.

Thank you!

Comment: Simply wrap your arrow function body in braces... `onClick={() => { removeUserHandler(user) }}`

Comment: Sounds like you either need to do what the lint rule wants (ie adding a catch or similar), or bypass (disable) the rule. What are you looking for in a potential answer here beyond what the linter is already telling you?

Comment: @Phil with that I start to get this error: Promises must be awaited, end with a call to .catch, end with a call to .then with a rejection handler or be explicitly marked as ignored with the `void` operator.

Comment: @CollinD I want to write the code as the linter wants me to but I don't know how. No matter what I try leads me to a different promise error like the one in comment above. And I don't want to disable the rule. I am willing to change the code to how it should be written

Comment: See [this typescript-eslint issue](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/4619). TBH, I'd just disable that rule as it would lead to useless extraneous code

Comment: I agree with what you are saying. In other projects I have not had this issue. But I was like let me see how can I solve this, did not think it will be this much pain :-)

Comment: Did you try prefixing the call with `void`?

Comment: @Phil yes and then I start to get the error: Expected  'undefined' and instead saw 'void'