# Promise returned where a void return was expected

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Typescript is giving me the following error
`const handleSignIn: (e: React.SyntheticEvent) => Promise<void> Promise-returning function provided to attribute where a void return was expected.` for the following code `<form onSubmit={handleSignIn}>`. It does the work and sends the registration email but I am still getting the error from the typescript. I tried to solve the issue with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63488141/promise-returned-in-function-argument-where-a-void-return-was-expected) and it does help with TS error but the code will not work.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { signIn } from "next-auth/react";

function RegisterPage() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");

  const handleSignIn = async (e: React.SyntheticEvent): Promise<void> => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      await signIn("email", {
        email,
        redirect: false,
        callbackUrl: "/",
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const registerForm = () => (
    <form onSubmit={handleSignIn}>
      <input
        type="email"
        className="form-control"
        value={email}
        onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
        placeholder="Your email"
        autoFocus
      />
      <br />
      <button type="submit" className="btn btn-raised">
        Sign In
      </button>
    </form>
  );
  return (
    <div className="container p-5">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
          <h4>Register</h4>
          {registerForm()}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default RegisterPage;
```

Comment: have you tried replacing  <form onSubmit={handleSignIn}> with  <form onSubmit={() => handleSignIn()}>

Sounds like it thinks form can't accept async functions but only normal ones?

Comment: @Vuk yeap I tried it and it helps with the error but the code will not work

Comment: You need to update what I sent to actually include the event

<form onSubmit={(e) => handleSignIn(e)}>, Sorry I just quickly typed the comment out

Answer (score 3):

This is a report about a misused promise.  According to [TS ESLint](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/pull/4623) update your `.eslintrc` config by adding

```
"rules": {
  "@typescript-eslint/no-misused-promises": [2, {
    "checksVoidReturn": {
      "attributes": false
    }
  }]
},
```