Promise-returning function provided to attribute where a void return was expected when updating react router to v7
I try to update react-router to v7. but get
 30:21  error  Promise-returning function provided to attribute where a void return was expected  @typescript-eslint/no-misused-promises

I get this on
import ArrowBackIosIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ArrowBackIos";
import IconButton from "@mui/material/IconButton";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

fonction foo() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
return (
  <IconButton
     color="primary"
     aria-label="back to Home page"
     onClick={() => navigate("/")}
  >
    <ArrowBackIosIcon fontSize="large" />
  </IconButton>
);
}

eslint config:
env:
  browser: true
  es2021: true
extends:
  - airbnb
  - airbnb-typescript
  - eslint:recommended
  - prettier
  - plugin:react/recommended
  - plugin:react/jsx-runtime
  - plugin:react-hooks/recommended
  - plugin:import/recommended
  - plugin:import/typescript
  - plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking
parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser"
parserOptions:
  project: "./tsconfig.json"
  ecmaFeatures:
    jsx: true
  ecmaVersion: latest
  sourceType: module
plugins:
  - react
  - "@typescript-eslint"
rules: {}
settings:
  import/resolver:
    typescript: []
ignorePatterns: ["dist", "vite.config.ts"]


eslint version:
"eslint": "^8.57.0",
"eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
"eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^18.0.0",
"eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
"eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^3.6.1",
"eslint-plugin-import": "^2.29.1",
"eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.8.0",
"eslint-plugin-react": "^7.34.1",
"eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^5.0.0",

I don't know how to fix this eslint issue, navigate is not a promise
Update: I try Promise returned in function argument where a void return was expected but doesn't fix issue

This is an eslint issue. Can you [edit] to share the complete error message and accompanying stacktrace so it's clear what specific unit of code you are referring to? I also can't help but notice that (a) you've a syntax error where fonction should be function and (b) you are attempting to use React hooks outside a React function, foo is just a regular Javascript function, not a React component. If you want it to be a React component it needs to be properly named using PascalCasing, e.g. Foo.

"I don't know how to fix this eslint issue, navigate is not a promise" - The navigate function does potentially return a promise. This might be relevant to your question, but your post is rather unclear and we need considerably more detail, e.g. a complete [mcve], your linter settings/configurations, etc.

I am aware of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63488141/promise-returned-in-function-argument-where-a-void-return-was-expected but both solution doesn't fix eslint issue

I don't have more log message from eslint

"I am aware of stackoverflow.com/questions/63488141/… but both solution doesn't fix eslint issue" Can you be more specific which two solutions you tried/applied that didn't work? There are 8 answers on that post.

function Foo() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleNavigate = () => {
    navigate("/");
  };

  return (
    <IconButton
      color="primary"
      aria-label="back to Home page"
      onClick={handleNavigate}
    >
      <ArrowBackIosIcon fontSize="large" />
    </IconButton>
  );
}

You need to wrap the navigate call in a function that explicitly returns void. This will satisfy the linter.
Or try this one
function Foo() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  return (
    <IconButton
      color="primary"
      aria-label="back to Home page"
      onClick={() => {
        navigate("/"); // Explicitly invoke navigate
        return; // Ensure the function returns void
      }}
    >
      <ArrowBackIosIcon fontSize="large" />
    </IconButton>
  );
}


with that I get Promises must be awaited, end with a call to .catch, end with a call to .then with a rejection handler or be explicitly marked as ignored with the `void` operator  @typescript-eslint/no-floating-promises and useless return
